# How do I compress a directory?

Tags: ios, gzip, tar, 7-zip

Hey guys I was wondering how would I gzip 7z tar or just regular zip a directory like this /var/Backups/Tones regular gzip won't do it because Tones is a directory and this site ss64.com/bash doesn't really tell much and I've searched google but what those people are talking about is computer based not mobile and I'd like to also make the archive password protected if its possible? If it helps any I'm using bash to do this.

This will be used on an iDevice like iPad iPhone and iPod when jailbroken; they have 7z gzip and tar.

Ok I got the compression for the directory to work using this:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /var/Backups
7z a -p{example} Tones.tar.7z
```

My problem now is when I go to extract that archive on my iPhone it doesn't even ask for a password am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You've got various options.

## 7z

```
tar -cf tarfile.tar path/to/files/
7z a tarfile.tar.7z tarfile.tar
```

This would create `tarfile.tar.7z`.  To help with clean-up, if you have it installed, you might use:

```
p7zip tarfile.tar
```

instead.

As for password protection, that is an option neither of `tar` nor `p7zip`.  If you're comfortable using the `7z` command, you can give it a `-p{password}` option, according to the man page.

```
7z a -p{password} tarfile.tar.7z tarfile.tar
```

This leaves `tarfile.tar` in place, so you'll need to clean up with something like:

```
if 7z q -p{password} tarfile.tar.7z tarfile.tar; then
  rm tarfile.tar
fi
```

A simpler option may be to compromise on your compression, and just use [ZIP](http://www.info-zip.org/mans/zip.html) with the `-9` option for the most compression it can muster.

Note that this isn't nearly as secure as a properly designed scheme using PGP or GnuPG, so if you can figure out that method (and the complexity doesn't compromise your security), you'll be further ahead.  Read about [PGP](http://www.pgpi.org/doc/) or [GnuPG](http://www.gnupg.org/), both of which will do what you need.

## gzip

Like 7z, you won't be able to password-protect your tar with a single command line. Further, the `gzip` command also doesn't provide any password protection.  So this also forces you to use a second step:

```
tar czf - path/to/files/ | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -e > tarfile.tar.gz.enc
```

Read the [documentation for openssl](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/openssl.html) to find out how to get it not to ask for a password on the command line.  Or:

```
tar czf tarfile.tar.gz path/to/files/
gpg --encrypt tarfile.tar.gz
```

Note that you'll need to set up gpg before this will work.

There may be (or "there certainly are") other ways to do this.  You may wish to treat this as a starting point for further research of your own.

## zip

If the `zip` command is included in your jailbroken iDevice, then you can use a command like:

```
zip -e -P{password} zipfile.zip path/to/files/
```

Note that the man page for zip says of the `-P` option: **THIS IS INSECURE**.  It goes on to say, *where  security  is  truly  important, use strong encryption such as Pretty Good Privacy instead of the relatively weak standard encryption provided by zipfile utilities.*

Any of these commands can be placed in a script.  If you want help writing the script, please post what you've got so far, so we can provide feedback.

That's all I've got.

Comment: 7z uses AES encryption with SHA-256 x 2^19 key. How is that not "properly designed scheme"?

Comment: 7z is fine.  It's the stuff wrapped around it that is almost certainly broken.  A shared-key approach *requires* that the password be distributed (or at least stored on the same system that will read the logs), which may be riskier than a public-key based solution with PGP.

Comment: Do I need a separate file with a command line to get this to work?

Comment: I'm using an iPhone my script will be used with an iPad and iPod as well

Comment: Ok I got this #!/bin/bash
cd /var/Backups
7z a -p{xd7@9#25ad$k} Tones.tar.7z

if 7z q -p{xd7@9#25ad$k} Tones.tar.7z Tones.tar; then
  rm Tones.tar
fi

exit 0 it worked the problem I have now is it didn't password protect the .tar.7z

Comment: Kevin, if you have more information that clarifies your question, please click the [edit link under your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11313598/edit) and make an update.  Comments do not format your code properly.

Comment: Ok I updated the question sorry about that I'm new to this site

Comment: Does anyone else have any solutions for me?

Comment: I suspect that you already have a number of working solutions, but you're implementing them badly.  For example, you should always quote words that contain special characters.  Your shell may interpret some characters in ways you don't expect, despite quoting (for example, `!` in tcsh).  Since you haven't told us your shell, we can't help you there.  But just as a start, are you including curly braces in your password?  You realize that `{password}` in the example code means that your password starts at the open curly brace and ends at the close?

Answer (score 2):

`tar czf your_dir.tgz your_dir/`
will create a compressed archive that most other zip programs can at least understand and unpack if you need to.

For password protection, though, there is no direct support in tar/gzip. Use the solution proposed by ghoti, or set up GPG/PGP and encrypt the tar before compressing it.

Comment: How would I password protect the archive?

Comment: I think I did this wrong tar cxf /var/Backups/Tones.tgz /var/Backups/Tones/

Comment: Nope, I did it wrong. Replace the 'x' in the command with a 'z'. Edited above.

Comment: Well it will be used on an iDevice like iPad iPhone and iPod when jailbroken they have 7z gzip and tar

Comment: He said tar/gzip or 7z, and tar compression uses gzip's algorithm.

Comment: I get tar: cowardly refusing to create a empty archive

Comment: is the directory you are passing empty? This works fine for me.

Comment: No the directory has media in it like Update.caf and more

Comment: This is what I put for the code tar czf /var/Backups/Tones/.tgz correct me if I did that wrong

Comment: No '.' before the .tgz

Comment: Either way it still cowardly refuses to create an empty archive which I can't figure out why

Comment: Here's what I'm working with http://pastie.org/4193691 I want to compress the directory /var/Backups/Tones into a password protected archive that I only know the password to to keep users from deleting system default tones

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier if I just put a password on the directory like .htaccess?

Comment: Um, no, you would encrypt _after_ compression, not before.  If you encrypt the tar file before compression, then you will get no compression.

Comment: I mean instead of making a compression could I use .htaccess to password protect the directory or would that work on mobile?

Comment: I have this #!/bin/bash
cd /var/Backups
7z a -p{xd7@9#25ad$k} Tones.tar.7z

if 7z q -p{xd7@9#25ad$k} Tones.tar.7z Tones.tar; then
  rm Tones.tar
fi

exit 0.   It works but 1 prob it doesn't password protect the archive.

Comment: Anyone have any ideas?